# Question about .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php cont.php?id=1
```

but If I surfing to **index.php?image=bla.jpg**

for some reason I see the page: **cont.php?id=1**

How can I do the only url **index.php** will open **cont.php?id=1** and not others like **index.php?image=bla.jpg**

?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the requested URI query as well:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ cont.php?id=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^index.php cont.php?id=1
```

That matches everything *beginning* with `index.php` (that's what `^` means).  You need to say that the path must *end* in that as well, which is indicated by the `$` sign. ([Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule))

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ cont.php?id=1
```

Escaping the `.` is also advisible, otherwise it matches any single character (e.g. index1php).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ cont.php?id=1
```

add doller sign after index.php

Comment: two important things to mention
1) escape the '.' character 2) use the RewriteCond attribute before the RewriteRule 3) [QSA] doesn't work because it means just to append the query string at the end. For your case, QSA is not the proper one. go with this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328316/question-about-htaccess/6328357#6328357)

Answer (score 0):

```
 RewriteRule ^index.php cont.php?id=1 [QSA]
```

You neew QSA attribute - it tell Apache to pass any query string to rewrited address